# Ho to use MediaElement with relative URL in Windows Phone 7.1?

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio-player

I proved everything but this code does not run in Windows Phone 7.1
private MediaElement media;

```
private MediaElement media;
    // Costruttore
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        media = new MediaElement();
        media.Source = new Uri("Risorse/Brani/00 Mai 1771.mp3", UriKind.Relative);
        media.Play();

    }
```

The file I mentioned exists and no error is thrown...

Comment: Are you trying to play sound effects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MediaElement control must be put into the visual tree. You can accomplish this by placing the element in xaml

```
<MediaElement x:Name="MyMedia"/>
```

Or in code

```
media = new MediaElement();
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(media)
```

Once it is in the visual tree, you will be able to play.