# Stream a mp3 file from internet in WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mediaelement

i'm writing an app to listening music, I used MediaElement.Source for the url , when I have a link like this:

```
http://mp3.zing.vn/html5/song/kHxGTknaVJFdDGGtyvHLG
```

then this will work

```
string url = "http://mp3.zing.vn/html5/song/kHxGTknaVJFdDGGtyvHLG";
MediaElement me = new MediaElement();
me.Source = new Uri(url,UriKind.Absolute);
```

but some of link won't play music, something like:

```
http://api.mp3.zing.vn/api/mobile/download/song/LGJGTLGNAVJNQQJTLDJTDGLG
```

or

```
http://api.mp3.zing.vn/api/mobile/source/song/LGJGTLGNAEXXELJTLDJTDGLG
```

I just don't know why, some links worked, some not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These below two link would work for you because  they are for streaming the audio

```
http://mp3.zing.vn/html5/song/kHxGTknaVJFdDGGtyvHLG
http://api.mp3.zing.vn/api/mobile/source/song/LGJGTLGNAEXXELJTLDJTDGLG
```

Below link is for Downloading file from the server so it would not helpful for you to Steaming audiio

```
http://api.mp3.zing.vn/api/mobile/download/song/LGJGTLGNAVJNQQJTLDJTDGLG
```

in Your code you are missing this:

```
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(me);
me.Play();
```

**The MediaElement control must be put into the visual tree.** You can accomplish this by placing the element in **xaml** or **cs** file

for more Refrence you can go through this Question : [Ho to use MediaElement with relative URL in Windows Phone 7.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326878/ho-to-use-mediaelement-with-relative-url-in-windows-phone-7-1)

Comment: Thank, so that we can't stream the "download" link, right ?